# How does visual studio (or Resharper ?) know that "Expression is always true"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ado.net, resharper

Using Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper.

Sample code:

```
    public void DoSomethingWithTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt.PrimaryKey != null) // XX
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

In the IDE, I get the warning: "Expression is always true" at line marked XX. My question is, how does the IDE (or Resharper ?) know that the DataColumn[] value of PrimaryKey will not be null ?

I know that if I used a tool like Reflector to see the inner workings of ADO.NET, I could come to the same conclusion, but how does Resharper do it ? Are such warnings 100% reliable ?

Comment: sorry for the dup. Any idea if such warnings are 100% reliable ?

Comment: Nothing is 100% reliable, but I trust ReSharper in these things myself. ReSharper won't flag this unless it is "sure" about this so in general I would say yes, you can trust this. But 100% reliable? You mean, no bugs at all in this code? Nobody is that perfect. The Jetbrains people are good, but they too have bugs in their code. I've yet to see a problem with this particular warning though. My advice: *go for it*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have reflector, maybe it uses a  decompiler?

It can indeed never be `null`, this is decompiled via `ILSpy`:

```
public DataColumn[] PrimaryKey
{
    get
    {
        UniqueConstraint uniqueConstraint = this.primaryKey;
        if (uniqueConstraint != null)
        {
            return uniqueConstraint.Key.ToArray();
        }
        return DataTable.zeroColumns;
    }
        // setter ...

// System.Data.DataTable
internal static readonly DataColumn[] zeroColumns = new DataColumn[0];
```

**Edit**: as shown in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067872/284240) resharper uses the `NotNullAttribute` for classes in the .NET- or NUnit Framework.

> We have analyzed a great share of .NET Framework Class Library, as
>   well as NUnit Framework, and annotated it through external XML files,
>   using a set of custom attributes from the JetBrains.Annotations
>   namespace....

Comment: ReSharper uses a library of external annotations (created by review/analysis of the .NET framework) but otherwise does not perform cross-assembly (or outside-solution) analysis.

Comment: @user2864740:  yes, i've also only just read the duplicate question's accepted answer. But maybe this answer is helpful anyway since resharper tries to find the answer even if there is no `NotNullAttribute` (in the current assembly). I've edited my answer to include it.