# SerializationInfo Instance Is Never Null?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, serialization, resharper

I'm messing around with writing custom exceptions and implementing serialization for them.  I've noticed that if I null check the instance of SerializationInfo before accessing one of its members, ReSharper tells me the check is redundant and that the instance is known to be not null.  It's not a value type, but poking around on the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/serializationinfo.cs) showed me there is no default constructor.  Is this how ReSharper can tell it won't be null?  Is there some other reason?  Is this possibly a bug?

Comment: Is it already being used somewhere else in code before that statement?

Comment: @BenjaminDrolet - It is being used as a parameter in a constructor which is derived from a base Exception constructor with the same parameter.  It's also being used as a parameter in an override of the base method GetObjectData.

Comment: @bubbleking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067819/how-does-resharper-know-expression-is-always-true) probably answers your question

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you call constructor of base Exception class. Something like this:

```
protected SomeException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            // Some work...
        }
    }
```

Resharper knows that internally base constructor checks for *info* parameter. I think it is in accordance to official [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz6bzkbf(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

Exceptions:
ArgumentNullException   - The info parameter is null.
SerializationException  - The class name is null or HResult is zero (0).

```
if (info == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
```

If base constructor called then you will get a value or exception.
So Resharper says that expression is always true. And this time it is correct because documentation most likely will never be changed.
But in many other cases I do not like what Resharper suggests.