# Why does resharper think asp.net Request["abc"] can never be null?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm using ASP.NET web forms and I have a fragment like this:

```
string errorId = Request["errorid"];
if (errorId != null) ...
```

Resharper says "Expression is always true" for this second line and wants to remove the condition.

The documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item(v=vs.110).aspx clearly says that if the specified key is not found, then NULL is returned.

Why does R# think that the indexer can never return null? is there anything I can do to fix it, other than ignoring the warning?

I'm using the latest version at the time of writing (2017.3.1)

Comment: Look at this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067819/how-does-resharper-know-expression-is-always-true).

Comment: @BWA so to summarize my understanding, someone at JetBrains has manually trawled through a load of .NET APIs and documented which ones can never return null, and hard-coded that into Resharper, but they have made a mistake in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet I posted was incomplete; the actual code was more like this:

```
string errorId = Request["errorid"];
log.Debug(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(errorId));
if (errorId != null) ...
```

What R# had correctly figured is that if errorId is null, the "log" line would have thrown an exception, and therefore by the time it got to the 'if' line, errorId cannot be null.